# Accessing Appfabric cache from another machine

Tags: asp.net

I have a computer(X1) where a web application built in VS 2010 runs and Appfabric is installed and used in this app. I have another computer(X2) where also Appfabric is installed. Both computers are connected in a workgroup.

For example, currently I have created a cache "NamedCache1" in X1 and using this to store value and referencing it from my app in X1. I have created a cache "NamedCache2" in X2 and I want to use this cache "NamedCache2" in my app. How can I acieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague as to where you are in configuring AppFabric. I'll assume you've run through the steps at one of the many Google results to configure AppFabric caching, such as [the one by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx). If you look at his CacheUtil class at that link, you can modify it to access two caches.

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CacheUtil
{
    private static DataCacheFactory _factory = null;
    private static DataCache _NamedCache1 = null;
    private static DataCache _NamedCache2 = null;

    public static DataCache GetNamedCache1()
    {
        if (_NamedCache1 != null)
            return _NamedCache1;

        //Define Array for 2 Cache Hosts
        List<DataCacheServerEndpoint> servers = new List<DataCacheServerEndpoint>(2);

        //Specify Cache Host Details 
        //  Parameter 1 = host name
        //  Parameter 2 = cache port number
        servers.Add(new DataCacheServerEndpoint("X1", 22233));
        servers.Add(new DataCacheServerEndpoint("X2", 22233));

        //Create cache configuration
        DataCacheFactoryConfiguration configuration = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();

        //Set the cache host(s)
        configuration.Servers = servers;

        //Set default properties for local cache (local cache disabled)
        configuration.LocalCacheProperties = new DataCacheLocalCacheProperties();

        //Disable tracing to avoid informational/verbose messages on the web page
        DataCacheClientLogManager.ChangeLogLevel(System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Off);

        //Pass configuration settings to cacheFactory constructor
        _factory = new DataCacheFactory(configuration);

        //Get reference to named cache called "default"
        _NamedCache1 = _factory.GetCache("NamedCache1");

        return _NamedCache1;
    }

    public static DataCache GetNamedCache2()
    {
        if (_NamedCache2 != null)
            return _NamedCache2;

        //Define Array for 2 Cache Hosts
        List<DataCacheServerEndpoint> servers = new List<DataCacheServerEndpoint>(2);

        //Specify Cache Host Details 
        //  Parameter 1 = host name
        //  Parameter 2 = cache port number
        servers.Add(new DataCacheServerEndpoint("X1", 22233));
        servers.Add(new DataCacheServerEndpoint("X2", 22233));

        //Create cache configuration
        DataCacheFactoryConfiguration configuration = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();

        //Set the cache host(s)
        configuration.Servers = servers;

        //Set default properties for local cache (local cache disabled)
        configuration.LocalCacheProperties = new DataCacheLocalCacheProperties();

        //Disable tracing to avoid informational/verbose messages on the web page
        DataCacheClientLogManager.ChangeLogLevel(System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Off);

        //Pass configuration settings to cacheFactory constructor
        _factory = new DataCacheFactory(configuration);

        //Get reference to named cache called "default"
        _NamedCache2 = _factory.GetCache("NamedCache2");

        return _NamedCache2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I followed the Scott Hanselman article during installing. I applied your code in my app in X1. GetNamedCache1() function works fine, but GetNamedCache2() generates error at this line _NamedCache2 = _factory.GetCache("NamedCache2");

Comment: It looks like for some reason NamedCache2 is not accessible from X1.

Comment: Are X1 and X2 configured as part of the same cache cluster? If so, try running Get-Cache in the AppFabric Powershell on both machines to make sure that NamedCache1 and NamedCache2 are on both. If not and they're individual clusters, make _factory into 2 variables, one for each of the get cache methods. Then remove or comment the line that adds server X1 in GetNamedCache2 and X2 in GetNamedCache1. Alternatively you could make both machines part of the same cache cluster.

Comment: If they're part of the same cache cluster and running Get-Cache in Powershell shows NamedCache2 is only on X2, there may be a configuration issue since it should show on both. Try running Get-CacheClusterHealth on each to make sure they can see each other. If that's okay, try running the create cache command on X1. If that fails, try exporting the configuration from X1 and import it X2, then run the create cache command to create NamedCache2 on X1.